# Beginniner: how to link an obj file to a project

Tags: c, object, linker, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to compile a particular project for the first time.  It's a hybrid of a modern VC 2019 project and an old VC 6 project.  I tried to push ahead by copying the contents of the VC6 project's main .c function into that of the VC 2019 project (don't ask), it is now saying there are "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol (A) referenced in function (B).

I can see that the symbol is from a precompiled external object with .h and .obj only, problem is I've copied the relevant .obj literally everywhere I can think of and the error remains.

Am I wrong to think that it just needs the obj file?  Or that it just needs to be put in the right place?

Comment: Why don't you compile everything in your new env?

Comment: If you compile all source files (not just `main.c`) in the new environment, then you should not need any `.obj` files from the old environment. Or don't you have access to the source code of the "precompiled external object"?

Comment: If you want the linker to use an `.obj` file when building a program, then you will have to edit the linker settings of the project. However, I'm not sure if old VC 6 `.obj` files are compatible with VS 2019.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel  I thought I didn't have the code for those objects.  Turns out I did :blush: